# update data in datagridview on new form

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

i am using VB in Visual Studio 2010

i have three form(MainForm, SaveForm, and updateform) where saveForm and updateform have same form design, in Mainform have 1 datagridview, two buttons(btnSave to show saveForm and btnUpdate to show updateform)
 is possible to update data on selected row in datagridview with the condition all the data on that row appear at updateform?

i have this coding

**this is in update form**

```
Dim idsend As String
Conn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(Konek())
        Conn.Open()
        Comm = New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        Comm.Connection = Conn
        Comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TabelSiswa WHERE No =" & idsend
        Reader = Comm.ExecuteReader()
        Reader.Read()
        txtName.Text = reader.getvalue(1)
```

**This is on Mainform**

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
FormUpdate.idSend = dgv.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value
```

Comment: what's the problem with your current code? pertanyaannya kurang jelas bro :)

Comment: sorry, the problem is, i can't update selected data/row in datagridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Vland solution will work,
but I think better practice will be if you keep variable `idsend` as Private, because it is used outside of class only once(passed to class instance)

```
Private _idsend As Int32
```

Then pass it's value to form through constructor

```
Public Sub New(inIdSend As Int32)
    _idsend = inIdSend
End Sub
```

And now you can use your id inside of `FormUpdate`

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, 
                          ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim id as Int32 = dgv.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value
    Dim update As New FormUpdate(id)
    update.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

Or if you don't want create connection to Database one more time - create a constructor with needed data from datagridview as parameters...

Answer (score 0):

The idsend in your updateform should be Public

Try with

```
Public Class updateform 
    Public Property idsend As String

    ...
End Class
```

and then pass the id value before opening your form

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim f2 As New FormUpdate
    f2.idsend = dgv.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value

    f2.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```